# Bottom half of scroll bar missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Once the vertical scroll bar appears on my site the bottom half of it seems to be missing. You can see the live site [HERE](http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00518833/COM601/assignment_1/index.html#) (go to "FURTHER READING" tab).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>History of Le Mans</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="JS/common.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="tab1" name="#tabContent1" class="activeTab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab2" name="#tabContent2">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab3" name="#tabContent3">The Circuit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab4" name="#tabContent4">Gallery</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="tab5" name="#tabContent5">Further Reading</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="tabContent1"></div>
      <div id="tabContent2">
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
              <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 4</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabContent3"></div>
      <div id="tabContent4"></div>
      <div id="tabContent5"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
  font-size: small;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#tabs {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -98px;
  width: 100%;
}

#tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -15px 0 0;

}
#tabs a {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #3D3D3D;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hover {
  border-bottom-color: #2AC7E1 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#content {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #3D3D3D;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0 0 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 98%;
}

.activeTab {
  border-bottom-color: #3D3D3D !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: right;
  top: -450px;
  right: 300px;
}

.bookPara {
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  top: -400px;
}

#accordion {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your issue involves the combination (on the content id) of `height:100%`, `position: fixed` and `top: 30px`.

Your height fills the window, is fixed in position and then pushed down 30px.

I don't really understand why you've structured the layout the way you have but you will need to remove one of the above constraints in order to prevent the page from extending beyond the bottom of the window.

Comment: I've updated my CSS in the original post, the problem with the vertical scroll bar is gone but I'm now having a horizontal scroll bar even though the content doesn't extend horizontally.